# JSP PrintWriter for multiple lines

Tags: jsp

I am trying to write some information to a text file. Each piece of information should be on a new line. The following code works however everything is printed on one line.

Should't the println() print to a new line? Why isn't it working?

```
<%
    String file = request.getParameter("page"); 
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String location = request.getParameter("location");
    String number = request.getParameter("number");
    String url = request.getParameter("url");

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));

    pw.println(name);
    pw.println(location);
    pw.println(number);
    pw.println(url);

    pw.close();
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the real benefit of JSP's and  do like this

```
<%
        String file = request.getParameter("page"); 
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String location = request.getParameter("location");
        String number = request.getParameter("number");
        String url = request.getParameter("url");

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));

        pw.println(name);
              %><br/>

        <%  pw.println(location);%><br/>
        <%  pw.println(number);%><br/>
        <%  pw.println(url);
                pw.close();
                                           %>
```

I don't know Why you are creating again `PrintWriter` object as JSP itself provide ["out" which is a printwriter object](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm) variable in scriplets.
There are some other good ways through which we can do this but according to your code, I found this way comfortable.
**EDIT:** if nothing works then you need to give a chance to `pw.printf( "%s" + "%n" , location);` Because this allows you to pass a formatted string of text to your PrintWriter. A good reason for using `printf` is to handle new line characters. The new line character differs, depending on which operating system you use. Windows will add the characters `\r\n` for a new line. But Unix systems just use `\n`. Using the printf function will ensure the correct encoding, no matter what the platform.

Comment: The <br/> tags didn't work. Everything is still on one line. I don't think the "out" command will help, out is, quote "This is the PrintWriter object used to send output to the client." I don't was to print back to the browser, I am saving into a text file??? But I'll give it a go.

Comment: what is `pw.out` ? I stated that out is the PrintWriter's object.So you need to call `out.println()` .You need to study some basics

Comment: writeln threw an error, but write works, however everything is still on one line. Even if I try pw.write(name + '\n'); everything is still on one line...Granted I'm new to this but I said out wouldn't work.

Comment: @Edit - make sense. And it appears to be working, in notepad++ and sublime, but in plain old notepad it is still one line. I am thinking it may have been more of an encoding problem than a code problem. I will go back and try some of the other commands. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Update: pw.printf(name + '\n'); works when viewed in sublime for example, but notepad is still one line - oh well.